# IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::Create returns kIOReturnNotReady

Tags: macos, dma, driverkit

I'm writing a user-space application in MacOS to work with DMA, in a similar fashion to Linux's dmabuf.

I created the memory descriptor with `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::Create(kIOMemoryDirectionInOut,(int)pow(10,5),0,&command->buffer)`. However, the return code I got was `kIOReturnNotReady`.

I signed the binary with `com.apple.developer.driverkit`, disabled SIP, and did `systemextensionsctl developer on`.

I'm trying to use the API for DMA on MacOS, similar to Linux's dma-buf.

Comment: `kIOReturnNotReady` is an odd return code for `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::Create()`. Are you seeing anything else in the system log that would suggest some kind of general problem with the dext?

Comment: I didn't create a dext, I'm just using DriverKit within a normal binary. Maybe that's the problem ("not ready" means the dext is not ready)? That feels weird though.

Comment: I don't even know how you managed to link against DriverKit frameworks in a regular user space binary. What you're trying to do won't work. I'm guessing `kIOReturnNotReady` reflects some kind of state in the Mach messaging connection whereby the kernel is expecting the other end to authenticate itself before calling APIs. This authentication isn't possible for a regular user space process, only a process running in the DriverKit sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use DriverKit APIs from outside a DriverKit extension. If you want to use these APIs, you need to use them in a dext.

Comment: This is likely the reason. Due to this, I just used IOSurface instead.

Comment: @DrownedSuccess `IOSurface` is great for sharing image data across process boundaries. If you want a more general shared memory mechanism, there are a few of those in macOS: There's [traditional POSIX shared memory](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/shm_open.2.html) and [XPC also supports memory sharing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xpc/1505572-xpc_shmem_create?language=objc), for example. (You didn't specify in your original question what the actual problem was you're trying to solve.)

Comment: I wanted something similar to Linux's DMA-BUF for MacOS.

Comment: I'm not *that* familiar with dma-buf, but as far as I'm aware it's mainly intended to be used for DMA and device access. DMA on macOS would only really be possible with PCIe/Thunderbolt devices, and those are only accessible via DriverKit. But you say you're in a regular user space process, so I'm guessing you're *NOT* after actual DMA from a device, but are on Linux using dma-buf to act as some kind of shared memory system. So you'd really need to specify what you actually need, because dma-buf doesn't exist on macOS, but whatever subset of dma-buf you're using might.